# run a single query on multiple databases

Tags: mysql

1)I have a table employee(emp_id, emp_name,emp_salary);
I want to find top 2 employees having max salary without using limit

2)how do i run a query so that it takes records from databses on two database mysql servers
this should be done in single mysql query

thanks in advance for any help or replies

Comment: looks like this gonna answer my first question. FAcebook block  .. need to reach home to read that.. :(  http://www.facebook.com/note.php?note_id=206034210932

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A single query can't talk to two database servers at once. It's just not allowed. But you can link the two servers using a [FEDERATED](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/federated-storage-engine.html) table. This makes the "remote" table appear as if it's really stored locally.

However, then you're still stuck to having to use a union query, unless the two tables can be JOINed somehow.

```
SELECT blah,blah,blah
FROM localtable

UNION

SELECT blah,blah,blah
FROM federatedtable
```

Answer (score 0):

So what exactly is wrong with the LIMIT?

```
select * 
  from (select * 
          from db1.employee
         order by salary desc limit 2 
        union 
        select * 
          from db2.employee
         order by salary desc limit 2
) emp
order by emp.salary desc limit 2
```

if employees in bd1 and db2 are certainly different or you dont want to remove duplicates change to `UNION ALL`

Comment: http://forge.mysql.com/wiki/Top10SQLPerformanceTips it  says LIMIT m,n may not be as fast as it sounds. Learn how to improve it and read more about Efficient Pagination Using MySQL

Comment: That performance tip refers to cases when you are using LIMIT with `m` being very big, in our case `m` is 0 (omitted) and this will give performance boost instead, esp if you have index on `salary` field.